# JQuery Ajax gets Redirected automatically without the cookies being set?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

When I use Jquery ajax call (post or get), and I get a redirect (302), it seems like Jquery is automatically following the redirect. In other words, it doesnt trigger complete or success callbacks until AFTER the redirect is followed.  Also, the set-cookies from the initial response is not being honored by the redirect.  In other words, the set-cookies from the initial response is populated with a bunch of stuff, but when the redirect happens, there are no cookies present.  So I have 2 questions.

1)  Is Jquery ajax call supposed to automatically follow redirects?  Is there a way to make it not follow a redirect?

and

2)  When it does follow redirects, are the cookies supposed to be set from the initial response?  Or are they supposed to be blank always?

Answer (score 0):

1. I thought AJAX calls are simply browser requests, which should follow redirections.
2. Why is there a Set-Cookie along with a 302? I'm not sure if I understand the question.

Comment: Sorry if I'm new at computers, but the 302 does have a set-cookie in the response, and when I browse to the page in question and do this whole thing manually, the redirect happens and the cookies are set properly.  But, when I try to do the same thing via Jquery/ajax (to automate it), the cookies are not being set and the redirect request always shows up as "canceled" in firebug.  I suspect it is because it does not see the proper cookies.